# cards image processing

Tags: image-processing, webcam

I want to build a program that can recognize typical playing cards.
is there an algorithm that can process an image from webcam and to determine the card type? 
if there is not- are there more simple algorithms that can be combined for this purpose?
thanks

Comment: http://digital.liby.waikato.ac.nz/conferences/ivcnz07/papers/ivcnz07-paper51.pdf

Comment: http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~gholling/home/files/IEEEHollinger.pdf

Comment: @rwong: Awesome. As I suspected, this is a perfect topic for academic research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some basic information to point you in the right direction. I suggest tackling the problem in two parts: a) webcam, and b) card recognition.

Part a) is not as hard as part b) and so I suggest that you ignore the webcam initially - get the algorithm working with several test images you've taken. Once card recognition works, you can then get your webcam working as your input.

Here's a wikipedia article about [object recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_recognition). The names of the algorithms are listed, so you'll be able to do some research into which algorithm(s) you might investigate.

Be warned: image processing and feature/object detection is not trivial. I suspect that this would make a very good masters or PhD project. I have very little experience in this area and your question is *very* general. I hope this helps you to get started.

*postscript:*

If you get this working well, the casinos will probably be interested. You could make some money, if you play your cards right.